# Rails regex exclude symbols end whitespaces between word

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm trying to mark every row that is within the two `#BLOCK` rows.

Also, I want to exclude all symbols `[""," ",{},(),\n]`

```
#BLOCK
#NAME {PC8}
#TYPE GHD3
#PROGRAM "FooBar" (2.0)
#DATE 20190501
#BASE 3740 "TXGH3789"
#BLOCK
```

Right now, I have two solutions but I want to combine them into one.

I am using Rubular and the links are here:

Example 1: https://rubular.com/r/bd2AxaHB2QLGpt

Example 2: https://rubular.com/r/vmxm2kugNhnDCS

I have tried these two solutions:

1. `(?<=#BLOCK\n)(.*)(?=#BLOCK)` This is working and it marks everything within the two `#BLOCK` rows.
2. `[^,{},(),""," ",\n]` This works to exclude these symbols but it doesn't mark the content between the two `#BLOCK` rows.

How can I combine both to get the expected result as I described at the beginning?

The expected result is two mark everything between the `#BLOCK` rows and exclude symbols like `[{},(),""," ",\n]`.

Comment: You should be able to do this using the `\G` construct. But, what do you mean by _mark_ ?

Comment: Changing the `ruby-on-rails` tag to `ruby` because I don't see any connection this has to the web framework.

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer? You don't want to see others? Please answer @sln's question (with an edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "mark" you mean *Match*, you can try this I guess.
It uses the `\G` construct.

(Note - Ruby uses `//m` option to mean *Dot-all*)

(**update** - don't let it go past the next block without restarting )

`/(?:(?:(?<=\#BLOCK\n)|(?!^)\G))[,{}()"\s]*\K(?!\#BLOCK\b)[^,{}()"\s](?=.*\#BLOCK\b)/m`

https://rubular.com/r/TxlU9yhiUJkrok

Explained
Note - this regex matches a single character at a time.

```
 (?:
      (?<= \#BLOCK  \n )            # A block behind
   |                              # or,
      (?! ^ )                       # Not the BOS
      \G                            # Start matching where last match left off
 )
 [,{}()"\s]*                   # Consume optional punctuation and whitespace
 \K                            # Disregard anything matched so far
 (?! \#BLOCK \b )              # Don't go past next block
 [^,{}()"\s]                   # Get a single non-punct nor whitespace char
 (?= .* \#BLOCK \b )           # Only if there is a block ahead
```

---

To match chunks of characters use this one.

`/(?:(?<=\#BLOCK\n)|(?!^)\G)[,{}()"\s]*\K(?=.+\#BLOCK\b)(?:(?!\#BLOCK\b)[^,{}()"\s])+/m`

https://rubular.com/r/kyhqnOtIrmrnJ7

Explained

```
 (?:
      (?<= \#BLOCK  \n )            # A block behind
   |                              # or,
      (?! ^ )                       # Not the BOS
      \G                            # Start matching where last match left off
 )
 [,{}()"\s]*                   # Consume optional punctuation and whitespace
 \K                            # Disregard anything matched so far
 (?= .+ \#BLOCK \b )           # Check that there is a block ahead
 (?:
      (?! \#BLOCK \b )              # Don't go past next block
      [^,{}()"\s]                   # Get a single non-punct nor whitespace char
 )+
```

Comment: What if the first row is `'#CELLBLOCK'` and last row is `'#BLOCKHEAD'`?

Comment: `#Cellblock` won't match. `#Block`head on the last row will match, better put some boundary there.

Comment: I was unaware of `\G`. Is it newish?

Comment: I'm having some difficulty following your answer. An attempt to compile the regex above raises an exception that `(?s)` is an "undefined group option (i.e., Ruby doesn't support that). That regex is different than the one you've used at rubular.com. The latter does not have `(?s)`. It has an `s` option (`/ms`), but Ruby does not support that...

Comment: ...When I execute `str.scan(r)`, where `str` is the example in my answer and `r` is you regex, it returns, `["#", "N", "A", "M", "E", "P", "C", "8", "#", "T", "Y", "P", "E", "G", "H", "D", "3", "#", "P", "R", "O", "G", "R", "A", "M", "F", "o", "o", "B", "a", "r", "2", ".", "0", "#", "D", "A", "T", "E", "2", "0", "1", "9", "0", "5", "0", "1", "#", "B", "A", "S", "E", "3", "7", "4", "0", "T", "X", "G", "H", "3", "7", "8", "9"]` Is that what is intended? We may of course have interpreted the question differently. Incidentally, you needn't escape `'#'` here.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - `Is that what is intended?` Dunno, I never ran or intended to do scan(). In fact, I don't know Ruby at all. Also, the inline modifier is not needed if Ruby doesn't support them. Just put them `//here`. Finally, you seem to be worried that a single character is returned at a time with the match. To get chunks, change the last part. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - I'm a regex expert. When I escape something like this `\#`, or replace a space with a `[ ]` it's for a reason. If you would like to know all my tricks, you can peruse my over 2200 regex posts.

Comment: I don't care about all your tricks, but I would like to know why you escaped `'#'` when it's not followed by `'{'`. I've learned about `\G` from your answer (which I upvoted), and would like to learn more. (Again, Ruby does not support `/s`).

Comment: @CarySwoveland - `//o` is a ruby trick. `/\#{/x` is my trick. So, you think you've learned `\G` ? It can be very tricky, be carefull !

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that you wish to extract words that fall between the lines `'#BLOCK'`, with the words separated by a string, each character of which is a character in the string `"^ {}()\"\n#"`. An alternative interpretation, which I will address as well, is that only the characters of those words are to be extracted.

A regular expression is called for in the title of the question (the adjective "Rails" should be struck, as meaningless). I recommend against using a single regular expression for this problem. The code I've given below is, in my opinion, more direct, easier to follow and test, and easier to maintain if requirements change in future.

**Code**

```
def exclude(str)
  arr = str.split(/^#BLOCK$/).drop(1)
  arr.pop unless str.end_with?('#BLOCK')
  arr.flat_map { |s| s.scan(/[^ {}()"\n]+/) }
end
```

**Examples**

```
str =<<END
cat
#BLOCK
#NAME PC8
#TYPE GHD3
#PROGRAM "FooBar" 2.0
#DATE 20190501
#BASE 3740 "TXGH3789"
#BLOCK
#DATE 20000101
#BASE 0473 "9873HGXR"
#PROGRAM "BarBaz" 3.0
#BLOCK
dog
END
```

```
extract str
  #=> ["#NAME", "PC8", "#TYPE", "GHD3", "#PROGRAM", "FooBar",
  #    "2.0", "#DATE", "20190501", "#BASE", "3740", "TXGH3789"]
```

Now form a string from `str` that beings and ends with the lines `'#BLOCK'`.

```
str1 = str.gsub(/^cat\n|^dog\n/, '')
puts str1
#BLOCK
#NAME PC8
#TYPE GHD3
#PROGRAM "FooBar" 2.0
#DATE 20190501
#BASE 3740 "TXGH3789"
#BLOCK
#DATE 20000101
#BASE 0473 "9873HGXR"
#PROGRAM "BarBaz" 3.0
#BLOCK
```

We see that

```
exclude(str1)
  #=> ["#NAME", "PC8", "#TYPE", "GHD3", "#PROGRAM", "FooBar", "2.0",
  #    "#DATE", "20190501", "#BASE", "3740", "TXGH3789", "#DATE",
  #    "20000101", "#BASE", "0473", "9873HGXR", "#PROGRAM", "BarBaz", "3.0"]
```

returns the same array as does `exclude(str)`.

**Explanation**

For `str` as defined above, the steps are as follows.

```
arr = str.split(/^#BLOCK$/)
  #=> ["cat\n",
  #    "\n#NAME PC8\n#TYPE GHD3\n...\"TXGH3789\"\n",
  #    "\n#DATE 20000101\n#BASE 0473...\"BarBaz\" 3.0\n",
  #    "\ndog\n"] 
arr = arr.drop(1)
  #   ["\n#NAME PC8\n#TYPE GHD3\n...\"TXGH3789\"\n",
  #    "\n#DATE 20000101\n#BASE 0473...\"BarBaz\" 3.0\n",
  #    "\ndog\n"] 
  str.end_with?('#BLOCK')
    #=> false 
arr.pop
  #=> "\ndog\n" 
arr
  #=> ["\n#NAME PC8\n#TYPE GHD3\n...\"TXGH3789\"\n",
  #    "\n#DATE 20000101\n#BASE 0473...\"BarBaz\" 3.0\n"] 
arr.flat_map { |s| s.scan(/[^ {}()"\n]+/) }
  #=> ["#NAME", "PC8", "#TYPE", "GHD3", "#PROGRAM", "FooBar", "2.0",
  #    "#DATE", "20190501", "#BASE", "3740", "TXGH3789", "#DATE",
  #    "20000101", "#BASE", "0473", "9873HGXR", "#PROGRAM", "BarBaz", "3.0"]
```

**Alternative interpretation of question**

If only the characters of the words in `extract(str)` are desired, one may write:

```
extract(str).join
  #=> "#NAMEPC8#TYPEGHD3#PROGRAMFooBar2.0#DATE20190501#BASE3740TXGH3789"
```

or

```
extract(str).join.chars
  #=> ["#", "N", "A", "M", "E", "P",..., "z", "3", ".", "0"]
```

or remove `'+'` in the regex that is `scan`'s argument:

```
def exclude(str)
  arr = str.split(/^#BLOCK$/).drop(1)
  arr.pop unless str.end_with?('#BLOCK')
  arr.flat_map { |s| s.scan(/[^ {}()"\n]/) }
end

exclude(str)
  #=> ["#", "N", "A", "M", "E", "P",..., "z", "3", ".", "0"]
```